# Where does Python look for my_script.py when I use python3.5 my_script.py?

Tags: python

When I call

```
python3.5 my_script.py
```

where does Python look for `my_script.py`? Just in the current working directory or is there a similar mechanism as with `PYTHONPATH` for `import` or `PATH` if I use the script with a shebang line?

(Before you consider this as a duplicate question: So far, the questions and answers on StackOverflow do not consider the mentioned case!)

Comment: In that directory where you are...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling the Python executable directly with `python <something>`, without any other command line arguments, will make the Python executable attempt to run the file `<something>`. So it will interpret that thing as a path and try to locate it.

So if you just write `python my_script.py`, it will look in the current directory. If you write `python ../my_script.py` it will look in the parent directory. If you write `python /home/foo/my_script.py` it will look in foo’s home directory.

As with any command, it’s a good idea to look at its [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/python) to get an idea of how it works:

> when called with a file name argument or with a file as standard input, it reads and executes a script from that file

Answer (score 0):

The argument supplied to python3.5 is a `path`. Here, it is not starting with `/` so it is a relative path, equivalent to `./script`

Python will not try to resolve the `path` to other locations for two reasons:

1. it is not common to do so
2. it avoids errors and security issues

Answer (score 0):

Python will look in the same directory from you launched the command. If the file isn't there, python will raise and error.